# Generate PDF from Excel data

Tags: php, pdf, google-drive-api, export, import-from-excel

I have been looking around and I found some topics talking about this already but not in any way as I was thinking of.

I am looking to do this entirely on the web through PHP or something close.

I could use FPDF to take a predesigned template PDF and add the correct data to specific positions, and then generate a PDF out of that and force a download.

But my main bump in the road is I would like to be able to get the data from an excel file that is edited daily.

So here is a scenario:

We have 1 big excel with multiple sheets (in this example 6)
Each sheet has 2 data row and 4 data columns like so:
[image: Sheet Data]

Lets call each sheet "Company 1", "Company 2" etc etc.

So a admin logs in into our back-end system (which is being made right now)
The admin chooses the customer called "Company 1".
The Excel is loaded up on the sheet for that company and the data is shown.
The admin can then check/edit the excel again before pressing the "Generate PDF" button.

Now in my head I think it would be interesting to maybe use google spreadsheets and their API to load up the Spreadsheet and the corret sheet/tab (or maybe a dedicated spreadsheet per company) and then get the data from that.

Is there anyone who has done something like this before? is there an easier way?
The final customer count will go up in about 100+ companies to generate the PDF for.

Comment: What about using excel as a datasource and then use something else to do the generating - in html or xml?

Comment: [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) can do this quite well, using either DomPDF, mPDF or tcPDF to handle rendering the worksheets as PDF. There's even examples in the `Examples` folder demonstrating how to do so

Comment: I looked at PHPExcel did some test. It's not really what I am looking for.
I've started using the Drive API to load the Spreadsheet and some jQuery Libraries to get the data from a json outputted version.